# special symbols in AWS S3 policies

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

My server issues the policy below to clients, so they can list the contents of their home dir in the bucket:

```
s3://abcd/public/USERNAME
```

From the client side I use AWS api with the policy to list the buckets.

All works fine with normal words, however, **when the username includes the character @ , I get a FORBIDDEN response.**

```
s3://abcd/public/@makeihan
```

I suspect it is interfering with those amazon ARN things, but apparently the @ is a valid and supported character in the keys (also tried to create the objects from the console and it works fine), I wonder if **I can escape it anywhere in the policy**, or this char is not supported?

Thanks in advance.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::abcd"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "public/@makeihan/*",
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::abcd/public/@makeihan",
                "arn:aws:s3:::abcd/public/@makeihan/*"
            ]
            }
        ]
}
```

Comment: What about replacing `@` with `%40` in the policy?

Comment: policies are generated by another system from encrypted token claims ... i shouldnt  touch that :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed two things in order to solve this, which included a bug in the SDK i was using:

1) specify `encoding="url"` on the `listObjects` request. When not specified, the SDK escapes the keys. When "url" is provided, the SDK uses the raw keys. - *btw-this sounds counter-intuitive to me*

```
        ListObjectsRequest listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest()
                    .withBucketName(S3_BUCKET)
                    .withDelimiter(DEFAULT_DELIMITER)
                    .withEncodingType("url")    // THIS DOES THE MAGIC
                    .withPrefix(prefix);
```

2) Update the AWS SDK. Older sdks have a bug regarding exactly this, so the rest of methods like `PutObject`, `GetObject`, etc.. were re-encoding again the keys.